# JAVA Spring boot : Required String parameter 'xxx' is not present for DELETE Method

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I tried to create some code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> testing(@RequestParam(value = "requestId", required = true) String requestId){
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(requestId, HttpStatus.OK);        
}
```

And I test that service using postman the response is success, no issue
But when I change the RequestMethod to DELETE

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/testing", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> testing(@RequestParam(value = "requestId", required = true) String requestId){
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(requestId, HttpStatus.OK);        
}
```

Response of that service is error :

```
{
"trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'requestId' is not present\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:112)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument
```

I set the requestId on body (form-data) same like i did when i call the POST method.
I only change the RequestMethod from POST to DELETE, any idea for this case?

Comment: `RequestParam` extracts the value from URI, not the body form-data

Comment: ya, but in this case, i want to use form-data as request. any other suggest?

Answer (score 1):

On delete method body data could be ignored. You can try requestId variable on path.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing/{requestId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> testing(@PathVariable String requestId){
    
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(requestId, HttpStatus.OK);        
}
```

You can check this [link](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/67)

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggest, and if i used the params for requestid, the result success.
but in this case, i want to use form-data as request. any other suggest?

Comment: form data(tag) only can be used with GET or POST HTTP request. maybe you can use some detour with hidden input tag. And check hidden value on every request.


`<form id="form" action="/testing" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
</form>`

Comment: i have same issue when we used method GET